# SleekXMPP Muc Room List and Discovering

Tags: python, xmpp, chatroom, multiuserchat

I'm new to XMPP :) I've been working with Ejabberd and sleekXMPP.
My question is How can online rooms are listed with sleekXMPP?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with this for a while as well.  Listing rooms is not part of MUC (**xep_0045**), but is instead a part of Service Discovery (**xep_0030**).

Some documentation is [here](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/wiki/XEP-0030:-Working-with-Service-Discovery#peforming-disco-queries), but it still required some experimentation to find the 'disco_items" array key.  Note that the "**iterator**" parameter only has effect if you also load **XEP-0059**.

It works as follows:

1. Ensure that you have 0030 loaded:

   ```
   xmpp.register_plugin('xep_0030')
   ```
2. Use it: (in my case this is part of the start() method of the class that extends sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP)

   ```
   result = self['xep_0030'].get_items(jid='conference.your.xmpp.server.com', iterator=True)

   for room in result['disco_items']:
       print "Found room %s, jid is %s" % (room, room['jid'])
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Akom has a good approach but personally I had problems with the iterator parameter.

A full example of Service Discovery implementation is available on :

https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/blob/develop/examples/disco_browser.py

With these features you are able to get identities, info and features of your XMPP server just by doing :

```
items = self['xep_0030'].get_items(jid='conference-server.com', node='', block=True)
```

And then :

```
for identity in info['disco_info']['identities']:
    print('  - %s' % str(identity))

for feature in info['disco_info']['features']:
    print('  - %s' % feature)

for item in items['disco_items']['items']:
    print('  - %s' % str(item))
```